# Azure AD saml configuration for GCP using graph API to configure "Sign on URL"

Tags: azure, google-cloud-platform, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

We are trying to configure Azure Active directory saml configuration using graph api for GCP after installing gcp application. We are following the AWS graph api saml setup URL for the same.

[App setup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/application-saml-sso-configure-api#set-basic-saml-urls)

We need to find a way to update "Sign on URL" in the below json code. For GCP "sign on URL" is mandatory field but for AWS it is optional.

```
{
  "web": {
    "redirectUris": [
      "https://www.google.com/a/xxxx.com/acs"
    ]
  },
  "identifierUris": [
    "https://google.com/a/xxxx.com"
  ]
}
```

Does anyone know how to setup this ?

I tried like below and many methods, nothing works

```
{
  "loginUrl": [
    "https://www.google.com/a/xxxx.com/ServiceLogin?continue=https://console.cloud.google.com"
  ]
  "web": {
    "redirectUris": [
      "https://www.google.com/a/xxxx.com/acs"
    ]
  },
  "identifierUris": [
    "https://google.com/a/xxxx.xom"
  ]
}
```

[image]

"Sign on URL" didn't mention in the following link too

[create application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-applications?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)
[update application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the option to add "Sign on URL" using graph API

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/servicePrincipals/ <Service Principal ID for Application>



{
"loginUrl": "<URL>"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud (G Suite) Connector doesn't provide Entity ID/Identifier value on Single Sign On configuration so when you uncheck the domain specific issuer option the Identifier value will be google.com. If you check the domain specific issuer option it will be google.com/a/<yourdomainname.com>

try like this and see.

Identifier (Entity ID): google.com

Reply URL: https://www.google.com/acs

Sign on URL: https://www.google.com/a/PRIMARY_DOMAIN/ServiceLogin?continue=https://console.cloud.google.com/,
replacing PRIMARY_DOMAIN with the primary domain name used by your Cloud Identity or Google Workspace account.

Comment: i guess you completely misunderstood my question and my issue

Comment: let me check again, if i can find any inputs.